# How to calculate variance with criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I would like to know how to calculate variance (VAR, VARA, VARP) with criteria as in AVERAGEIF and AVERAGEIFS. The VARIF function does not seem to exist. This question also applies to others functions such as median, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) function can be used to first select the parts of the range that meet your criteria. That result can then be passed to VAR (e.g. `=VAR(FILTER(source_range, condition))`).

`FILTER` can also be used to filter one column based on a condition on another column. For example, if you have columns:

```
x | 1
y | 2
x | 3
```

You can find the `VAR` for the rows that have `x` in the first column like this:

```
=VAR(FILTER(B:B, A:A = "x"))
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to apply the filter in one column  and to the variance of another. For example if I have a table with 2 columns  like this I want to filter for X then do variance with 1 and 7:                                                                                                        x 1                                                                                                                   z 2                                                                                                                   x 7

Comment: @Legion Updated the answer to include info on how to filter in one column and get the values from another column. You might also want to update your original question to be more specific.

Comment: @Legion: That's important information to include in your question. Comments are meant to be temporary.